# Почему функция при изменении размера экрана не устанавливает style элементу в html?

Tags: javascript, функции, resize

HTML

```
<menu class="menu">
    <div class="overlay"></div><!-- overlay нуждается в style -->
    <nav class="nav-bar">
        <button class="mn-btn"></button>
    </nav>
    <ul class="item-list">
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    </ul>
</menu>
```

JS

```
var overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);

    function resize(){
        var radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(window.innerHeight, 2) + Math.pow(window.innerWidth, 2)),
            diameter = radius * 2;

        overlay.style.width = diameter;
        overlay.style.height = diameter;

        overlay.style.marginTop = -radius;
        overlay.style.marginLeft = -radius;
    }

    resize();
```

Мой `overlay`, это часть анимации, который должен изменять ширину и высоту (css) постоянно используя формулу, но у меня что-то опять не работает. Ничего не происходит, в консоли ошибок нет. Если в консоль написать `resize();` выведет "undefined". Что не так со скриптом?

Comment: Не указаны единицы измерения. Если пиксели, то нужно писать `overlay.style.width = diameter + 'px';`, и так далее. А `undefined` выводится потому что функция ничего не возвращает - точнее говоря, она возвращает _ничего_ :]

Answer (score 0):

Я понятия не имею почему `style` не устанавливался, но решил установить инлайн стили через `setAttribute`. Буду признателен, если расскажите, почему так работает, а так как наверху нет. Вот код JS:

```
var overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);

    function resize(){
        var radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(window.innerHeight, 2) + Math.pow(window.innerWidth, 2)).toFixed(0);
            var diameter = radius * 2;

        console.log(radius + ' ' + diameter)

        overlay.setAttribute('style', 'width: ' + diameter + 'px; ' + 'height: ' + diameter + 'px; ' +
                             'margin-top: ' + -radius + 'px; ' + 'margin-left: ' + -radius + 'px;');
    }

    resize();
```